# Soda mixed with lemon juice

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I mixed 1 tbsp of soda and 1 squeeze of lemon juice in a glass. There was strong reaction with a lot of foam. What caused such a reaction?

Comment: Acid bas reaction

Comment: If you did this experiment without knowing this reaction will follow, and discovered this independently, then congrats, you're good little experimenter. It does not harm to learn at least some basic chemistry beforehands. Mixing some other household items can be more dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Soda is sodium carbonate. Lemon juice contains citric acid. What you witnessed was a classic reaction of carbonate with acid to generate carbon dioxide, water and the salt of the acid. It can be a vigorous reaction with a lot of gas evolution - which caused the foaming.

Comment: Actually baking soda is sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: The OP did not specify baking soda